# Vincular 3 tabelas em uma consulta SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou em uma duvida quase que mortal não sei será possível executar com apenas uma query. Tenho três tabelas no banco onde elas se relacionam com chaves estrangeiras até esse momento tudo bem estou conseguindo relaciona-las. O problema se torna onde a Tabela Imagens possuí nenhuma ou várias imagens ligada a um post, somente então quero retornar os dados da postagem, com o usuário que postou e as imagens caso houver, essa parte da imagem que está me intrigando, quero pegar somente as URLS das imagens mas em vez disso ele duplica a postagem e me retorna junto com as urls diferentes.
Estou executando essa query abaixo:

```
SELECT P.*, U.fistname, U.lastname, U.username, PI.url
FROM posts as P
INNER JOIN user as U ON P.User_id = U.id
LEFT JOIN post_has_image as PI ON PI.Posts_id = P.id
WHERE U.id IN (SELECT User_id1 FROM followers WHERE User_id = 1);
```

Já o resultado é:

[image: Tabela]

Gostaria do seguinte resultado:

2 message first2 2 harry potter harrypotter url url url(já que estão 3 urls na tabela imagem)

3 massage first3 2 harry potter harrypotter null

4 message first4 3 hermione granger hermione null

Se a montagem da tabela está errada ou existe alguma maneira de ter esse resultado em uma única query, sei que executando duas consultas consigo retorna mas gostaria de saber se realmente existe uma solução para ser executado em apenas uma query.

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Considerando que o campo urj é uma string pesquise pela função de agregação `GROUP_CONCAT()` e utilize a cláusula GROUP BY adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesse caso específico, você pode usar um sub-select, uma vez que está selecionando apenas uma coluna da tabela estrangeira, o que evita você colocar todas as outras colunas no group by. Caso não queira um sub-select, terá de escrever a query completa inclusive tirando o *

Dito isso, basta você agrupar várias linhas em uma só, neste caso utilizando a função [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-group_concat-function/)

```
SELECT 
    P.*, 
    U.fistname, 
    U.lastname, 
    U.username, 
    (Select  GROUP_CONCAT(PI.url) from post_has_image as PI WHERE PI.Posts_id = P.id) as imgs
FROM posts as P
INNER JOIN user as U ON P.User_id = U.id
WHERE U.id IN (SELECT User_id1 FROM followers WHERE User_id = 1);
```

por padrão, todas as URL serão separadas por vírgula, caso queira, é possível informar outro separador.

Comment: Certo, sua query funciona perfeitamente. Também apliquei o outro método que você e o @anonimo citaram que não era utilizar o sub-select e sim já utilizando o cancat e um group by. Ambas funcionam corretamente, existe a mais adequada ou tanto faz entre elas?Já apredendo mais hoje, não sabia que existia esse GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: acredito que não seja questão de "mais adequado" e sim que depende do que está utilizando, nesse caso, coloquei como sub-select pois seria apenas uma coluna da tabela "estrangeira" e evitaria o group by.